# mysql alter table order by not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have searched over net a lot. What I could understand is that this thing has been faced by many people before me and it has also been filed as `mysql` bugs. But I couldn't find any solution to this. The problem is just that I can't get this command working-

```
alter table areas order by area_name;
```

I get this **warning**-

```
ORDER BY ignored as there is a user-defined clustered index in the table 'areas'
```

I just want to sort the table on the basis of '`area_name`', that is, names of areas. Just to add, I am trying to do this in the database of my `laravel app`.

Comment: And you don't want to do this in the query itself?

Comment: @Strawberry i wanted it to be permanent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the db engine is **InnoDB**, then you can't do this.

*[From the doc:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)*

> **ORDER BY does not make sense for InnoDB tables** because InnoDB always
>   orders table rows according to the clustered index.